# Can ServiceStack.SessionFeature's session use custom session cookie name?

Tags: session, cookies, servicestack

I found that SessionFeature has hard-coded const values:

```
public const string SessionId = "ss-id";
public const string PermanentSessionId = "ss-pid";
```

Is there any way to customize them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're hard-coded constants.